# Leverage the work done in one SQL query to simplify a second one?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a database with, among others, the following two tables:

`classes` is a straightforward table that has one row per class in a class schedule.

`sessions` is a table that characterizes the days and times that each class meets, where each row is capable of expressing a notion like:

> "Tuesdays | Jan 22-Mar 5 | 6-9pm"
>   "Tuesdays & Thursdays | Jan 22-Mar 7 | 6-9pm"
>   "Monday-Thursday | Jan 21-24 | 3-6pm"
>   "Saturday | Mar 9 | 9am-4pm"

and so on.

There is guaranteed to be at least one row in `sessions` for each row in `classes`, and for certain classes there may be two or more associated session rows.

At present, I'm using two different queries to get the class and session information for the classes that match a particular set of criteria, like this:

```
select c.class_id, c.title, c.instructor, c.num_seats, c.price
  from classes c
  join classes_by_department cbd 
    on (cbd.class_id = c.class_id)
  join /* several other tables */
    on /* several other join conditions */
 where cbd.department_id = '{$dept_id}'
   and /* several other qualifying conditions */
;
```

and this:

```
select s.class_id, s.start_date, s.end_date, s.day_bits, s.start_time, s.end_time
  from sessions s
  join classes c
    on (c.class_id = s.class_id)
  join classes_by_department cbd
    on (cbd.class_id = s.class_id) 
  join /* the same other tables */
    on /* the same other join conditions */
 where cbd.department_id = '{$dept_id}'
   and /* the same other qualifying conditions */
;
```

This works fine, and -- at least in the current application -- the tables aren't big enough, and the traffic isn't heavy enough, for two queries to be a problem. Nevertheless, it strikes me as a bit wasteful, and I'm wondering if there isn't a way to better leverage the work already done by the first query to perform the second one (rather than what amounts to running the same query twice and just selecting different columns).

Of course I realize that I could just select all the relevant columns from `classes` and `sessions` in a single query (the second one), but I like the fact that in the current approach, the first query delivers exactly one row per qualifying class, rather than as many rows as the class has session records. I would need to restructure the existing logic that processes the query results if I merged the queries. (Yeah, I know, waah...)

One solution that occurred to me is to collect all the `class_id`s returned by the first query into a vector (since I have to iterate through those results anyway) and then format the contents of that vector as the content of a *value-list* for an `IN` clause, so that the second query would simply become:

```
select s.class_id, s.start_date, s.end_date, s.day_bits, s.start_time, s.end_time
  from sessions s
 where s.class_id in (/* value-list */);
```

I'm not too worried about the scalability of such a solution, as I understand that [huge SQL queries are no big deal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/96593/1337498). Plus, it could take advantage of an index defined over `sessions.class_id`.

But... well... it's just not very satisfying to someone who's looking to improve his SQL chops, which I'll freely admit are pretty rudimentary. It feels inelegant, and not very "SQL-ish," or whatever the SQL equivalent to the term *Pythonic* is.

Can anyone suggest something more appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical way to do what you want is to use views.  Define your first query as:

```
create view vw_MyClasses as
    select c.class_id, c.title, c.instructor, c.num_seats, c.price, cbd.department_id
    from classes c
         join classes_by_department cbd 
         on (cbd.class_id = c.class_id)
         join /* several other tables */
         on /* several other join conditions */
   where /* several other qualifying conditions */
```

Then your class query would be:

```
select *
from vw_MyClasses
where department_id = '{$dept_id}'
```

Then, your second query can be:

```
 select s.class_id, s.start_date, s.end_date, s.day_bits, s.start_time, s.end_time
 from sessions s
 where s.class_id in (select class_id from vw_MyClasses 
                                      where department_id = '{$dept_id}');
```

Or, what may be more efficient in MySQL:

```
 select s.class_id, s.start_date, s.end_date, s.day_bits, s.start_time, s.end_time
 from sessions s
 where exists (select 1 from vw_MyClasses mc where mc.class_id = s.class_id limit 1)
```

There is a very good reason for doing this.  Repeating such logic in multiple queries becomes a maintenance nightmare.  As you modify the logic in one place, it is very easy to forget to make the modifications in all places.  Sometimes, views are not sufficient, so you may need to use user defined functions, as explained [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-functions.html).

Also, if the criteria are so useful, you might want to put flags in the class table to identify them.  This requires maintaining them in some way, such as nightly updates or using triggers.

Comment: +1 to hardening the second query against changes in the first one. Could you explain a bit more what you mean about putting "flags" in the class table? (FWIW, the classes table only undergoes major changes once a quarter, and at such times I can force any required update afterward.)

Comment: @Hephaestus . . . I don't know what the flags are. But say one is being taught by Professor X.  If this is important, add a flag in the class table (or a separate "ClassDetails" table) for IsTaughtByX.  Of course, you know have to maintain this is and similar flags, so it may not simplify the overall problem.  On the other hand, it might make things easier for reporting if others are using the database.

Comment: Leaving aside "flags" for the moment: It's my sense that views are intended to be relatively long-lived, and their SELECT statements can't be parameterized -- at least not in MySQL. The application in question has to support casual online browsing by diverse users, so unless I've misunderstood something (entirely possible!), it seems I'd have to spin up a new view each time a user wants to see a different department's classes, or varies one or more of the other qualifying conditions. If so, is  this really a win?

Comment: If the selection criteria is simply by user, then you would write a view that included the user in the select columns.  The application would then add a `where` clause to make the appropriate selection.  A different view for each user is bad, in general.

Comment: The reality is even worse, I fear: each user can supply his/her own values for department, skill level (e.g., "entry-level|intermediate|advanced"), minimum/maximum price, etc., etc. I rebind the formal parameters in the query string  with user-supplied values for each page view requested. (I denoted a formal parameter in the OP with the PHP-ish syntax _{?param}_ -- sorry for any confusion in case this syntactic style was unfamiliar.)

Comment: Oops, my syntax was wrong.  See the modification I just made.  Put the department_id in the `select list,` then use it in the `where` clause.  You may not want all the columns in the view . . . you can select the ones you want.

Comment: Oho, I think I see now. I've seen references elsewhere to using views to de-normalize tables -- and if I correctly understand your recast `select` statement, it seems that's the essence of what you're suggesting. (Yes?)

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty I wouldn't bother. Firstly it works just fine an seems fairly elegant to me from what you've told us. Secondly, if there's no reason to bring back extra data on the second query then don't do it. Thirdly and by far the most important is that as it currently stands it is fairly easy to understand what's happening. You may not always be the only person trying to decipher this and it is important that the code is readable by someone else. Over complicated SQL queries are not nice.

I think it is just fine as is and it's SQL-ishness is good.

Comment: Well, one advantage of replacing the second query with the one that uses the `IN` condition is that it renders it impervious to changes in the complicated set of joins and conditions in the first query, which currently have to be duplicated in the second. Even if that parallel code update goes off without a hitch, a reader of the code still has to convince him/herself that the two sets of joins and conditions are actually the same. No such problem in the modified second query, which never has to change as long as the first one continues to select c.class_id, irrespective of other details.